# Set a layer-list as a view's background by code

Tags: android

In the listview's adapter I set the childs' background with:

```
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_checked);
```

And here is the background's file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <color android:color="@color/gold" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <nine-patch
            android:src="@drawable/bg_base_image"
            android:dither="true" />    
    </item> 
    <item>
        <bitmap 
            android:src="@drawable/bg_stripes_golden_image"
            android:antialias="true"
            android:dither="true"
            android:tileMode="repeat" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Although as you can see this drawable is a `<layer-list>` and contains a bitmap with a repeated image. The problem is when I set the background by XML it works properly, but when I set it by Java the background is not repeated and the image is just stretched. Is there other way to set this type of backgrounds by Java?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to create the entire layer list in code using a [LayerDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html#LayerDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%5B%5D%29). I think you would just call `getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_layer1)` on a `Resources` object (this can be obtained by calling `context.getResources()`) to get each layer and put it into a `Drawable` array to construct the `LayerDrawable`. Then set the background drawable of the view to your `LayerDrawable`.

Example:

```
//Method to get the LayerDrawable
private LayerDrawable getLayerDrawable(){
    Resources res = context.getResources();
    Drawable layer1 = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.first_layer);
    Drawable layer2 = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.second_layer);
    //...
    Drawable layerX = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.x_layer);

    return new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{layer1, layer2, layerX});
}

//Wherever you're setting the background, just do:
view.setBackgroundDrawable(getLayerDrawable());
```

Comment: Yes, if you could provide any example i would be pleased, I tryed to use LayerDrawable but it stills the same. I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I added the layerlist's code to my question. As you can see it has a color, a ninepatch and a bitmap. I created a `ColorDrawable` and a `BitmapDrawable` and I didn't obtain the result I wanted. Are you sure this works with my layer-list?